# getting exception :javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 550 5.2.1 Mailbox cannot be accessed

Tags: java, email, outlook

I'm getting this exception when sending email via outlook.

```
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "outlook.office365.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```

but from gmail I can send mail but I can't send via outlook..
Any body help me how to fix this...

No, its not duplicate..

if I pass wrong username and password its showing me as **"authentication failed"**,but when I give correct username and password its showing as **"mail box cannot be accessed"**

Comment: No in my case if i give wrong username and password its showing me as "authentication failed",but when i give correct username and password its showing as "mail box cannot be accessed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5.2.1: Mailbox cannot be accessed

### Possible Cause:

The mailbox cannot be accessed. The mailbox may be offline, disabled, or the message has been quarantined by a rule.

### Additional Info to solve:

Check to see if the recipient database is online, the recipient mailbox is disabled, or the message has been quarantined.

### Solution using command:

> Mailbox cannot be accessed. Perhaps the message is too large.
>   Alternatively, the mailbox has been disabled, or is offline. Check the
>   recipient's mailbox. Else it could be a permissions problem,
>   particularly on a Public Folder. If so, try this PowerShell Command:
>
> ```
> get-PublicFolderClientPermission "\ProblemFolder"
> ```

Resource Link:

1. http://osticket.com/forum/discussion/87831/smtp-authentication-failure-office-365
2. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Explanation-of-Enhanced-5b062775